# Reactjs music track application - pause currently playing tracks so others can play

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a reactjs application that is listing an array object of music tracks in a stack. The array maps over a waveplayer component that has play/pause capabilities.

I want to try and fix the components - so that when a user plays one track, and if they try to play another - it pauses the last track - so we don't have an uncontrollable situation of multiple tracks playing at once.

What is the best way of architecting the flag and control mechanism for this?

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-lake-8tsz3n

Here is my stack js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import SoundBite from './SoundBite';

import './SoundStack.scss';

class SoundStack extends Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
        isPlaying: "",
        isStopped: ""
    };
        
        this.isPlaying = this.isPlaying.bind(this);
        this.isStopped = this.isStopped.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
  
  }

  isPlaying(resp){
    console.log("isPlaying", resp);
  
    this.setState({
        isPlaying: resp
    })
  }

  isStopped(resp){
    console.log("isStopped", resp);
  
    this.setState({
        isStopped: resp
    })

    //remove from isPlaying
    if(this.state.isPlaying === resp){
        this.setState({
                isPlaying: ""
            })
    }

  }  

  render() {    
        let that = this;

      return(
        <>
                {/*this.state.isPlaying*/}
                {/*this.state.isStopped*/}

            <ul className="sound-stack">
              {
                this.props.stack.map(function(item, i){
                 return (
                  <li key={i}>
                    <SoundBite 
                      id={item.id}
                      title={item.title}
                      artist={item.artist}
                      url={item.track}
                      isPlaying={that.isPlaying}
                      isStopped={that.isStopped}
                      //autoPause={that.state.IsPlaying === item.id? true: false}
                    />
                  </li>
                );
               })
              }
            </ul>
        </>
      )
  }
}

export default SoundStack;
```

and here is the wave component itself

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import WaveSurfer from 'wavesurfer.js'
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import PlayArrowIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PlayArrow';
import PauseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Pause';

import MicIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Mic';

import './SoundBite.scss';

class SoundBite extends Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
        isPlaying: false,
        autoPause: this.props.autoPause
    };
 
    this.waveformDomRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.startWaveSurfer(this.props.url);
  }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // You don't have to do this check first, but it can help prevent an unneeded render
        
        let that = this;

        /*
    if (
      JSON.stringify(nextProps.autoPause) !== JSON.stringify(this.state.autoPause)) {
    //if (nextProps.data !== this.state.data) {
      //console.log("PROPS HAVE CHANGED FOR CHART");        
      this.setState({ autoPause: nextProps.autoPause });       
      console.log("PAUSE THIS RECORDING")        
    }
    */    
  }

  startWaveSurfer(url){
    this.waveformDomRef.current.innerHTML = "";

        const wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
          "container": this.waveformDomRef.current,
          "height": 40,
          "splitChannels": false,
          "normalize": false,
          "waveColor": "#8f8f8f",
          "progressColor": "#5fdd74",
          "cursorColor": "#ddd5e9",
          "cursorWidth": 2,
          "barWidth": 3,
          "barGap": 3,
          "barRadius": null,
          "barHeight": null,
          "barAlign": "",
          "minPxPerSec": 1,
          "fillParent": true,
          "url": url,
          "mediaControls": false,
          "autoplay": false,
          "interact": true,
          "dragToSeek": false,
          "hideScrollbar": false,
          "audioRate": 1,
          "autoScroll": true,
          "autoCenter": true,
          "sampleRate": 8000          
        })

        wavesurfer.on('interaction', () => {
          wavesurfer.play();
        })

    this.setState({ 
      wavesurfer: wavesurfer
    });
  }

  playFile(){
    this.state.wavesurfer.playPause();

    if(this.props.isPlaying){
        this.props.isPlaying(this.props.id);
    }

    this.setState({ 
      isPlaying: true
    });
  }

  pauseFile(){
    this.state.wavesurfer.pause();

    if(this.props.isStopped){
        this.props.isStopped(this.props.id);
    }

    this.setState({ 
      isPlaying: false
    });     
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sound-bite">
        <Grid container spacing={1}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>

                            <div className="wrapperWave">
                                <h3>{this.props.title}</h3>
                                <h4>{this.props.artist}</h4>
                                
                                <div className="innerWrapper">
                              <div className="controls">
                                  {this.state.isPlaying
                                    ? <PauseIcon className="pauseIcon" onClick={()=>this.pauseFile()} />
                                    : <PlayArrowIcon className="playIcon" onClick={()=>this.playFile()} />
                                  }
                              </div>
                                    <div className="waveForm" ref={this.waveformDomRef} id="waveform"></div>                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>     
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SoundBite;
```

Comment: Rather than storing `isPlaying`, check `waveplayer.isPlaying()` as needed. https://wavesurfer.xyz/docs/classes/wavesurfer.default#isPlaying.isPlaying-1

Comment: well - its really a case of pushing that back to the parent - so it can autopause whats playing if another is played

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do this, would be to keep track of whats currently playing and stop everything else, rather than having two diverged states

```
this.state = {
    currentPlayingId: null
}
```

Now, what we need is to have refference to each Soundbite file, so we can control it directly

```
 <SoundBite
       id={item.id}
        title={item.title}
        artist={item.artist}
        url={item.track}
        isPlaying={that.isPlaying}
        isStopped={that.isStopped}
        ref={(ref) => (item.ref = ref)}
        />
```

Now we can build logic around this, where we compare stored track id with actuall track id of played song.

I did build you an example here - hope it helps https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-https-kq2xw6

Comment: glad to hear! @TheOldCounty